# Как сложить два очень больших числа?

Tags: javascript

Сложность заключается в запоминании единицы при сложении и добавлении её на следующей итерации.

```
longNumber1 = '2'
longNumber2 = '149'

//сравниваются числа,и в то которое меньше по длинне добавляются нули

if (longNumber1.length > longNumber2.length) {
    var abs = longNumber1.length - longNumber2.length
        for (var i = 0; i < abs; i++) {
        longNumber2 = '0' + longNumber2
    }
} else {
    var abs = longNumber2.length - longNumber1.length
        for (var i = 0; i < abs; i++) {
        longNumber1 = '0' + longNumber1
    }
}

var str = '' //результат сложения двух чисел

var currentNum = '' //если в результате сложения число двузначное, то берем второе число и записываем на эту позицию
var nextPos = 0 //и запоминаем единицу в будущем

for (var i = longNumber1.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    if ( (Number(longNumber1[i])) + (Number(longNumber2[i])) < 10 ) { 
        str = Number(longNumber1[i]) + Number(longNumber2[i]) + str 
        nextPos = 0
    } else {
        str = Number(longNumber1[i]) + Number(longNumber2[i])
        str = String(str)
        
        currentNum = (str.slice(1,2)) //берем вторую цифру двузначного числа
        str = currentNum // записываем ее на эту позицию 
        nextPos = 1 //т.к число двузначное то мы должны прибавить единицу к след.цифре
    }    
}   

console.log(longNumber1)
console.log(longNumber2)

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ходу исполнения кода Вы затираете значение `str`. Вам нужно было выбрать другое название переменной для `str` в блоке `else`.

И всегда используйте `;` в JavaScript!

Я сделал минимально необходимые правки в стиле, в котором написан весь код. Но, должен заметить, что стиль пока очень хромает. Всё можно сделать гораздо более оптимально. Ну ничего, научитесь - со временем сделаете.

```js
longNumber1 = '999';
longNumber2 = '149';

//сравниваются числа, и в то, которое меньше по длине, добавляются нули

if (longNumber1.length > longNumber2.length) {
  var abs = longNumber1.length - longNumber2.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < abs; i++) {
    longNumber2 = '0' + longNumber2;
  }
} else {
  var abs = longNumber2.length - longNumber1.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < abs; i++) {
    longNumber1 = '0' + longNumber1;
  }
}

var str = ''; //результат сложения двух чисел

var currentNum = ''; //если в результате сложения число двузначное, то берем второе число и записываем на эту позицию
var nextPos = 0; //и запоминаем единицу в будущем

for (var i = longNumber1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (Number(longNumber1[i]) + Number(longNumber2[i]) + nextPos < 10) {
    str = Number(longNumber1[i]) + Number(longNumber2[i]) + nextPos + str;
    nextPos = 0;
  } else {
    twoNumbers = Number(longNumber1[i]) + Number(longNumber2[i]) + nextPos;
    currentNum = (String(twoNumbers).slice(1, 2)); //берем вторую цифру двузначного числа
    str = currentNum + str;
    nextPos = 1; //т.к число двузначное то мы должны прибавить единицу к след.цифре
  }
}

if (nextPos) { str = '1' + str; }

console.log(longNumber1);
console.log(longNumber2);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  a = [...a].reverse()
  b = [...b].reverse()
  
  for (var q=0; q<b.length; ++q) {
    if ((a[q] = ~~a[q] + ~~b[q]) > 9) {
      a[q] -= 10
      b[q+1] = ~~b[q+1] + 1
    }
  }
  
  return a.reverse().join("")
}

console.log(sum("999", "999"))
console.log(sum("9", "999"))
console.log(sum("999", "9"))

var a = "536425458245238754832461239874613469012"
var b =                      "908435378596458490"

console.log(sum(a, b))
console.log(sum(b, a))
console.log(BigInt(a) + BigInt(b) + "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один сумматор **положительных** чисел - на любое количество аргументов, заданных в виде строки или числа

```js
function sum() {
  let result = [];
  let mind = 0;
  let arr = [...arguments].map(a => [...a + ""].reverse());
  let length = arr.reduce((s, a) => s > a.length ? s : a.length, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let digits = arr.map(num => (+num[i]) | 0);
    let value = digits.reduce((sum, digit) => digit + sum, 0) + mind;
    mind = value / 10 | 0;
    result.push((value % 10) + "");
  }
  return ((mind || "") + result.reverse().join("")) || 0;
}

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(123));
console.log(sum(123, '8933', 12345));

var a1 = '923456789012345678901234567890';
var a2 = '9876598765';
console.log(a1, '+', a2, '=');
console.log(sum(a1, a2));
console.log(sum(a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2, a2));
console.log((+a2) * 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  var n = Math.max(a.length, b.length)

  a = a.padStart(n, 0)
  b = b.padStart(n, 0)

  var res = Array(n), d = 0

  for (var q=n-1; ~q; --q) {
    if ((res[q] = d + +a[q] + +b[q]) > 9) {
      d = 1, res[q] -= 10;
    } else {
      d = 0
    }
  }
  
  if (d) {
    res.unshift(1)
  }
  
  return res.join("")
}

console.log(sum("999", "999"))
console.log(sum("9", "999"))
console.log(sum("999", "9"))

var a = "536425458245238754832461239874613469012"
var b =                      "908435378596458490"

console.log(sum(a, b))
console.log(BigInt(a) + BigInt(b) + "")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string str(int a)
{
    ostringstream temp;
    temp << a;
    return temp.str();
}

string summ(string a, string b)
{
    if (a.size() > b.size()) b.insert(0,a.size()-b.size(),'0'); 
    else if (b.size() > a.size()) a.insert(0,b.size()-a.size(),'0');
    string c = string();
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = a.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int s = (a[i]-'0') + (b[i]-'0')+f;
        if (s < 10) 
        {
            c += str(s);
            f = 0;  
        }
        else
        {
            c += str(s%10);
            f = s/10;
        }
    }
    if (f > 0) c += str(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size()/2; ++i) swap(c[i],c[c.size()-1-i]);
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    cout << summ("183716563142637213617253612378173192839","39871623516341234516731531873131313121313");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]